# Convert String to Integer(Object) Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, java-stream

I want to convert a string to an Integer Array.
So basically i have a string of integers separated by spaces such as: "10 2 3 100"
I am trying to convert this to an Integer Array. All the answers I've searched for converts it to an int array. Of course, I can convert this to a int array, then turn the int array to an Integer array.

```java
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(string.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); 
//then a method to turn this into an Integer[]
```

Can you guys tell me if there is a shorter way to do this? (Like in one line)
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `IntStream`, you still want the `Stream` type (`Stream<Integer>` specifically), so instead of `mapToInt`, you should call `map`. Then to convert the resulting `Stream<Integer>` to an array, call `toArray(Integer[]::new)`:

```
Arrays.stream(string.split(" "))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```